# get data from different apis

Tags: api, repository-pattern, solid-principles

I'm developing api that get data from other apis (facebook, google ...). My idea is to create different repositories for every api. For exampl:

```
Interface ReaderRepositoryInterface
{
   getEvents ();
   getComents ()
}

class FacebookReaderRepository implements ReaderRepositoryInterface
{
   getEvents()
   {
     //call the api facebook method
   }

   getComments()
   {
     //call the api facebook method
   }
}
```

GoogleReaderRepository ...

Every class (FacebookReaderRepository, GoogleReaderRepository ...) will be in infrastructure and implements the methods that ReaderRepositoryInterface has. So the idea is from application services get data from specific repository and create entity with the information obtained.

I want to know if i'm applying solid the right way?

Comment: what language do you use for this?

Answer (score 0):

What you plan to do here is a good application of the SOLID principles so far.
Be careful about what will come later:

Be sure that in these other parts of your code, your code should remain implementation-agnostic. For example, if you fetch some data in a controller:

```
<?php

// doing some stuff - begins

$repository = $this->getRepository();

$events = $repository->getEvents();

// doing some stuff - continues

/**
 * @return ReaderRepositoryInterface
 */
private function getRepository()
{
    $repository = new FacebookReaderRepository();

    return $repository;
}
```

The idea here is that in the "doing some stuff", your code must be aware he is given a ReaderRepositoryInterface and only uses the function that comes with it. He must be not aware that the `$repository` is, in fact, a FacebookReaderRepository. This is SOLID applied.
The benefits of this approach are that you can easily replace a FacebookReaderRepository by a TwitterReaderRepository without modifying your "doing some stuff" code. Only modify the content of your `getRepository()` method.

You might also be careful about the "Interface segregation principle": if your FacebookReaderRepository gets too big, maybe you might want to create a FacebookApiClient that only handles HTTP calls, being used by a FacebookReader by performs some processing on fetched data, and this one will implement the ReaderRepositoryInterface.